# Hibernate criteriaQuery - left join

Tags: mysql, hibernate, join

How can I apply left join using criteria query, i am only able to find inner join condition on internet.

```
        Criteria cr = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(A.class, "a").createAlias("a.division", "division");                  
        List<A> list = cr.list();
```

division is a entity present in class A, This is returning me inner join results. I want to apply left join on division entity :

```
select * from A as a left join divisions as division on division.id = a.id;
```

Table A data :

```
    id  name        division_id
    1   first name  1
    3   sec name    2
    6   fourth name 2
    5   3rd name    NULL
```

Table division data :

```
    id  type
    1   F
    2   G
```

Inner join :

```
select * from A as a inner join division where a.division_id = division.id
```

Inner join result :

```
+----+-------------+-------------+----+------+
| id | name        | division_id | id | type |
+----+-------------+-------------+----+------+
|  1 | first name  |           1 |  1 | F    |
|  3 | sec name    |           2 |  2 | G    |
|  6 | fourth name |           2 |  2 | G    |
+----+-------------+-------------+----+------+
```

Left join query :

```
select * from A as a left join division on division.id = a.division_id;
```

Left join result :

```
+----+-------------+-------------+------+------+
| id | name        | division_id | id   | type |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+------+
|  1 | first name  |           1 |    1 | F    |
|  3 | sec name    |           2 |    2 | G    |
|  6 | fourth name |           2 |    2 | G    |
|  5 | 3rd name    |        NULL | NULL | NULL |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+------+
```

Comment: you can use a `where` clause after the join, but if you showed the db structure, some sample data and the result you want, you would get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want left join, you can mention it in `createAlias`. Default is `inner join`

```
Criteria cr = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(A.class, "a")
      .createAlias("a.division", "division", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);     // Add join type            
List<A> list = cr.list();
```

[`CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#createAlias%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29)